# How can I move past this 2NF to achieve a proper normalization of the table up to 3NF

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, 3nf

[image]

Can someone help with the normalization of this table up to 3NF?
Here's what I have done till now:

UNF

Student [Student Name, {Course ID, Course Title, Lesson No, Lesson Title, Lesson Status, Last Accessed, Instructor ID, Instructor Name}]

1NF

Separating Repeating data and groups:

Student [S.N, Student Name]

S.N. added as primary key for the table.

Course [Course ID, Course Title, Lesson No, Lesson Title, Lesson Status, Last Accessed, Instructor ID, Instructor Name, S.N FK]

Course ID selected as the primary key.

2NF

Student [S.N, Student Name]

This table stays the same because there is no partial dependency.

Course [Course ID, Course Title, Lesson No, Lesson Title, Lesson Status, Last Accessed, Instructor ID, Instructor Name, S.N FK]

Course ID = Course Title, Instructor ID, Instructor Name

Here I don't think course ID gives me Lesson No does it? So, should I make Lesson No a composite primary key along with Course ID?

Comment: You have four entities: Student, Course, Lesson, and Teacher.  Ask yourself, what's the relation between my entities?  For example, a Student can take 0 to many Courses.  A Course can have 1 to many Lessons.  Keep going until you have defined all relationships.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? How are you 1st stuck, following what process, justified by what reference/reasoning? What are the specific givens & goal for that? What exactly was your assignment? ["UNF" &"1NF" have no agreed meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) And higher NFs are typically defined per a 1NF. So give your definitions & preferably also textbook name & edition. One doesn't normalize to 3NF by going through 2NF; that can preclude good designs. FDs are fundamental to normalization to higher NFs, yet you don't mention them.

Comment: PS Are you normalizing that table value or a table variable that could hold that value? If a variable, were you told that you are allowed to infer certain things from the given value about other values the variable can or cannot hold? Normalization to a 1NF is not "Separating Repeating data and groups" in a way consistent with what you did. "primary key"s do not matter, CKs do. "there is no partial dependency" is not a characterization of 2NF. "gives me" is informal & unclear; use the technical terms you were given, according to what they mean, according to their definitions. Etc etc.